# Windows troubleshooting menu after dual boot menu

Tags: dual-boot

I just installed Xubuntu 12.04 along with Windows XP on my desktop (I know, XP is darn old, but I don't think Windows 7 will run smoothly on my 1 GB of RAM).

The installation process was without any hiccups, but when I restarted the system and selected Windows XP from the dual boot menu, the Windows troubleshooting screen came, you know, the screen with :

```
"Windows has encountered a problem. We're sorry for the inconvenience. 
What do you want to do? Start Windows normally, boot in safe mode...."
```

After I selected `Start Windows normally`, Windows XP booted fine and everything works fine.

If everything works fine, is the error message just a flunk?

Is everything fine on my system and Windows is just showing an unnecessary error message?

Comment: need more info does that happen everytime u boot into XP or just that instance..

Answer (score 0):

This is likely caused by the Ubiquity (the Xunbuntu installer) shrinking of the Windows partition.

You shouldn't worry about it.